# I want the iOS system to get the wireless LAN URL, which is Macaddress. Compatible with iOS8 or higher

Tags: objective-c, mac-address, ios10.2

My previous method does not work after iOS10.2. Now want to find the way to get Macaddress, can be compatible with iOS8.0 or more

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions.

Comment: Show your code and explain why it doesn't work, then someone will probably be able to help you. Edit your question to do this. HTH